# How to configure bake to work on CLI.

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I'm new to cakePHP and I've been having difficulties getting bake to work.  I've added the path to my php.exe to my environment variables bit still can't get it to work. I still get the error that it's not a recognized internal or external command. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Silly me. In version 3.x the cake executable has been moved from **app/console** to **bin/cake**.  However if on Windows remember that from your project folder you can invoke the bake command thus **bin\cake bake** and not **bin/cake bake.**